# dpkg-shlibdeps: failure: no dependency information found for a dynamic library

Tags: qt, package, meego

I have an qt application project MyAppSetting to run on Meego, using quazip (an open source library in http://sourceforge.net/projects/quazip/),

when I try to run it, following warnings and errors came out:

```
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: symbol crc32 used by debian/myappsetting/usr/lib/libquazip.so.1.0.0 found in none of the libraries.

dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: symbol __aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1@GCC_3.5 used by debian/myappsetting/usr/lib/libquazip.so.1.0.0 found in none of the libraries.

dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: symbol deflateInit2_ used by debian/myappsetting/usr/lib/libquazip.so.1.0.0 found in none of the libraries.

dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: symbol adler32 used by debian/myappsetting/usr/lib/libquazip.so.1.0.0 found in none of the libraries.

dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: symbol inflateEnd used by debian/myappsetting/usr/lib/libquazip.so.1.0.0 found in none of the libraries.

dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: symbol deflate used by debian/myappsetting/usr/lib/libquazip.so.1.0.0 found in none of the libraries.

dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: symbol deflateEnd used by debian/myappsetting/usr/lib/libquazip.so.1.0.0 found in none of the libraries.

dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: symbol inflateInit2_ used by debian/myappsetting/usr/lib/libquazip.so.1.0.0 found in none of the libraries.

dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: symbol inflate used by debian/myappsetting/usr/lib/libquazip.so.1.0.0 found in none of the libraries.

dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: symbol get_crc_table used by debian/myappsetting/usr/lib/libquazip.so.1.0.0 found in none of the libraries.

dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: 1 other similar warnings have been skipped (use -v to see them all).

**dpkg-shlibdeps: failure: no dependency information found for /opt/QtSDK/Madde/sysroots/harmattan_sysroot_10.2011.34-1_slim/usr/lib/libquazip.so.1 (used by debian/myappsetting/opt/MyAppSetting/bin/MyAppSetting).

Packaging Error: Command '/opt/QtSDK/Madde/bin/mad dpkg-buildpackage -nc -uc -us' failed.Exit code: 2

Error while building project MyAppSetting (target: Harmattan)**

When executing build step 'Create Debian Package'
```

I have already built the quazip for Harmatton to a dynamic lib libquazip.so.1, used by MyAppSetting in pro file like following:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/lib -L./ -lquazip
```

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, it looks like libquazip uses symbols from zlib, but doesn't link to zlib itself.

The __aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1@GCC_3.5 warning is a separate problem, but I've found material that says that this can be ignored: http://lists.debian.org/debian-arm/2012/06/msg00040.html

Comment: yes, it is ignored. the point is "pkg-shlibdeps: failure: no dependency information found for /opt/QtSDK/Madde/sysroots/harmattan_sysroot_10.2011.34-1_slim/usr/lib/libquazip.so.1"